# What is this coordinate format?

Tags: coordinates

I was looking at the data posted on this page
https://datadryad.org/handle/10255/dryad.83330

The readme file says that the coordinate column is given as

> Coordinates (UTM, midpoint): WGS84 32V

and in the main data file some examples of entries are

```
NM9890048100
NM9920047850
NM9975046050
PM0170046800
PM0110045100
PM0120046100
```

Coordinate entries start with either NM or PM. Any idea how I can convert these to longitude/latitude?

Comment: [@eev2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/128576/eev2), what is your main file extension?

Comment: @Taras It's an excel file. You can get it from the above link.

Comment: NM and PM are 100 x 100km grid squares in UTM 32V see: http://www.mjolner.org/filer/div-filer/Kart-kompass-UTM-GPS-RAR.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [MGRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_Grid_Reference_System). V is in northern hemisphere, so it translates to UTM 32N (EPSG 32632). The leading N translates to a x offset of 500000, P is 600000. Second letter M translates to a y offset of 6600000. So NM9890048100 is x 598900 y 6648100 in EPSG 32632. This translates to lat 59.95839/lon 9.27103.

I used [this web service](http://legallandconverter.com/p50.html) for looking up the numbers.